# C# Selenium How to use Safari Technology Preview

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

How we instruct Selenium to use Safari Technology Preview in C#?

In Java, we can set that using the method [`setUseTechnologyPreview`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariOptions.html#setUseTechnologyPreview-boolean), but unable to find similar method in C# class `SafariOptions`.

We have tried by using `options.AddAdditionalCapability('useTechnologyPreview', true)`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and there's not a lot of documentation available. It is possible, though. The webdriver executable lives inside the application for the preview. Set up a webdriver service to use it. (I have a few extra options included...)

```
SafariDriverService serv = SafariDriverService.CreateDefaultService("/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/", "safaridriver");
                SafariOptions opts = new SafariOptions();
                opts.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
                opts.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptInsecureCertificates, true);
                opts.AddAdditionalCapability("cleanSession", true);
                webDriver = new SafariDriver(serv, opts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
We are using Selenium grid to run the test and we are instantiating the driver as follows:-
`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(seleniumHostUrl), capabilities)`
Could you please let us know how we can setup the driver service here.

Comment: If anyone is looking for how to do it with Ruby and Capybara. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663481/how-to-setup-capybara-with-safari-technology-preview-in-ruby/44663482#44663482

Answer (score 0):

For remote Selenium, we are using the following approach:

```
Dictionary<string, object> remoteSafariOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
remoteSafariOptions["technologyPreview"] = true;
safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
safariOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("safari.options", remoteSafariOptions);
browser = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(seleniumRemoteGridUrl), 
safariOptions.ToCapabilities());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the browser names in the current versions of SafariDriver:

```
            var safariService = SafariDriverService.CreateDefaultService("/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/", "safaridriver");
            var safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
           safariOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Safari Technology Preview");
            driver = new SafariDriver(safariService, safariOptions);
```